# i can not import database from sqlserver to hadoop using sqoop

Tags: hive, bigdata, hbase, sqoop

using cloudera quick start vm 5.12.0 with 8 gb ram and 64gb storage
**
I can not import database into hadoop when I write the command of sqoop list-database it work with me and show me the databases on my sql server but now i can not import it into hadoop
could you tell me where is the wrong with this command and how can i fixed it **

```
`[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc://localhost/Drugs --username=Rabab_Hussien31 --password=123ttt --table drugs --hive-import

Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
23/02/12 14:49:28 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.0
23/02/12 14:49:28 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
23/02/12 14:49:28 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
23/02/12 14:49:28 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
23/02/12 14:49:29 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string: jdbc://localhost/Drugs
    at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.init(ImportTool.java:95)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:609)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
`
```

```
sqoop list-databases   --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.56.1:1444 --username Rabab_Hussien31 --password 123ttt
```

this command work with me and all the databases I have appears to me but I can not import them

I want to import the database on Hbase and query it with hive

Comment: can you use `--connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.56.1:1444 ` as jdbc connector in sqoop ? YOu are using localhost and that may be the problems

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i used the same localhost in list-databases on sqoop it shows me the database i have      ,could you explain to me where is the problem ?

Comment: i thioght may be localhost is cusing this issue. But i think difference between table import and sqoop list command is table import need a location/table structure to import. make sure you are using correct command to import.